# Create a simple twig filter

Tags: symfony

I get this error message when i create since i have created a simple twig filter. The message is not clear at all.

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template
>   ("Warning: Illegal offset type in app/cache/dev/classes.php line
>   3342")

My filter:

```
class simpleFilter extends Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array('simpleFilter' => new Twig_SimpleFilter($this, 'simpleFilter'));

    }

    public function simpleFilter($value)
    {
        return 'test'.$value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'some_extension';
    }
}
```

My config

```
my.twig.extension.simpleFilter:
    class: Bundle\Twig\Filter\SimpleFilter
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: You need back slashes in front of Twig_.  See the example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html.  And change simpleFilter to SimpleFilter.

Comment: Try and manually clear your cache. `rm -rf app/cache/*` Then warm it up `php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: I use some use statements, I don't need backslashes. I did it anyway and it doesn't change anything

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to use Twig_Filter_Method

```
public function getFilters()
{
   return array(
      new Twig_Filter_Method('simpleFilter', array($this, 'simpleFilter'))
   );
}
```

even if i do not know the difference beetween them.

Comment: `Twig_Filter_Method` is deprecated and will be removed. You *must* use `Twig_SimpleFilter`

Comment: It wasn't when I did it

Answer (score 3):

Try to change your `getFilters` to look like this:

```
public function getFilters()
{
   return array(
      new Twig_SimpleFilter('simpleFilter', array($this, 'simpleFilter'))
   );
}
```

Comment: I suspect you have a backslash in front of Twig_SimpleFilter?

Comment: I do. OP didn't have one in sample code, so I assumed there is an appropriate use statement to accommodate that.